# First time trying Android Studio. Emulator won't start - Linux

Tags: android, android-studio

OS: Linux Mint 19.1
Android Studio: android-studio-ide-191.6010548-linux
CPU: AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 965 Processor
RAM: 16GB
API Level: 22 ; Android: 5.1

I am following this guide: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/build-your-first-android-app/#2

I've reached **step 5** but the emulator doesn't start.

- I have tried using both Hardware and Software GPU.
- I have set `hw.audioInput` and `hw.gps` to `no`

Running the emulator from `~/Android/Sdk/tools` using the command `./emulator -avd 7_WSVGA_Tablet_API_22 -netspeed full -netdelay none` returns the following:

```
emulator: WARNING: encryption is off
emulator: WARNING: Host CPU is missing the following feature(s) required for x86 emulation: SSSE3
Hardware-accelerated emulation may not work properly!
emulator: WARNING: Not all modern X86 virtualization features supported, which introduces problems with slowdown when running Android on multicore vCPUs. Setting AVD to run with 1 vCPU core only.
emulator: INFO: QtLogger.cpp:68: Warning: QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL context, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled ((null):0, (null))


host doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.ssse3 [bit 9]
checkValid: hw configs not eq
```

So a bunch of warnings that I can't clear.

What do you think ?

Comment: What Android Version are you using in Emulator?

Comment: API Level: 22 ; Android: 5.1.

Comment: check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSSE3#CPUs_with_SSSE3) is your CPU listed?

Comment: Not really, no.

Comment: But API Level: 22 ; Android: 5.1 is the lowest I can go in Virtual Device Configuration with any Tablet. Does this mean that I can't program on my PC ?

Comment: Sorry but you may not be able to run emulator, you can try to install [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/fun-zone/)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure HW virtualization support is enabled in bios. Also look here: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.html